# Not Able To Plot Graph Using Networkx in Python

Tags: python, networkx

I have CSV file in below format,

```
A,B,23
C,D,21
D,B,12
```

where each node represents a station and weight represents the running time between them. 
I need to build a graph using networkx having node as station and running time as edge between them.
I have created a multilevel dictionary as below format

```
{'A': {'B': '29'}, 'C': {'D': '26'},'C': {'B': '12'}
```

I've not been able to create graph and draw it using Networkx.

After creating the graph I will also be applying Dijstra's Algorithm to find shortest path

I have total 1500 rows in my CSV file from which I am converting into a dictionary. Is there any other efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a single question and explain what you have tried?

Comment: How did you try to create the graph, and what went wrong? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here is my code for reading through CSV file and making a multilevel dictionary

my_dict = {}

with open('final_graph.csv') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        my_dict[row[0]] = {row[1]: row[2]}

I want to convert my_dict into a visible network graph with all nodes and edges

Comment: Please edit the question and put your code in.  The question should be understandable without reading comments.  Please also explain what you have tried in order to convert `my_dict` to a networkx graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have your data in a dictionary like `{'A': {'B': '29'}, 'C': {'D': '26'}, 'C': {'B': '12'}}` because the keys are not unique (you have `C` two times as a key). I suggest using a 2D list instead, where e.g. `'A': {'B': '29'}` would become `['A', 'B', '29']`.

I assume that your graph is undirected (the edge A->B is the same as B->A) and that you don't have more that one edge between two nodes.

Here is my example with only 3 edges where I draw the nodes (and their names) and the edges (and their weights). I also converted your weights to numerical values since you stated that you will be doing computations on your graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    ['A', 'B', '29'],
    ['C', 'D', '26'],
    ['C', 'B', '12']
]

G = nx.Graph()  # new empty undirected graph

for row in data:
    src_node = row[0]
    dest_node = row[1]
    weight = float(row[2])  # convert weight to a number
    G.add_edge(src_node, dest_node, weight=weight)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # compute graph layout
nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=700)  # draw nodes and edges
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)  # draw node labels/names
# draw edge weights
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
# show image
plt.show(G)
```

Output:
[image]

Note that it could take a while for Python to draw the graph if you have a lot of nodes and edges (the image might also be cluttered). It's worth mentioning that with the [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) layout function you can get different images each time you run the code.